# Concatenação Create Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, concatenação-de-string, create

Estou tentando criar uma tabela a partir do email do usuário, e estou usando o código abaixo:

```
 $email = $_SESSION["email"];
 echo $email;
 $create=mysql_query("CREATE TABLE userpics_'$email' (id_user VARCHAR(60), id_pic VARCHAR(200), id_tipo INT(2))");
        if (mysql_query($create))
        {
         echo "TABLE created.";
        }
        else 
        {
         echo "Error in CREATE TABLE.";
        }
```

Se o usuário for o `teste@teste.com.br,` o nome da tabela deve ser `userpics_teste@teste.com.br`.
Com esse código, eu recebo a mensagem de "Error in CREATE TABLE." conforme o `else`.
Alguém sabe me dizer onde posso estar errando? Talvez seja algum erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Provavelmente é por conta do arroba(@) no nome da tabela, tente utilizar utra forma, sem caracteres especiais.

Comment: @touchmx tem razão, pode ser isso mesmo. Vou fazer alguns outros testes com outro tipo de informação. Obrigado.

Comment: O mysql permite tabelas com "@". O problema não é esse não.

Comment: O caractere `.` é utilizado para separar o nome do banco de dados do nome da tabela. Creio que isto esteja criando uma confusão. Use quoted identifiers (nome entre crases).

Answer (score 2):

Reescreva o create adicionando aspas inglesas ` entre o nome da tabela. Pode fazer assim:

```
$create = mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `userpics_".$email."`(  
                            `id_user` VARCHAR(60),
                            `id_pic` VARCHAR(200),
                            `id_tipo` INT(2)
                        );"
);
```